# MBP - Retina, 15-inch, Mid-2015 - Yosemite: Deletes take long over time

Tags: macos, ssd, file-management

More about this laptop: 16GB RAM, 1TB SSD, case sensitive file system

Using activity monitor, I can see that I am not using any swap space.

I noticed recently that over time, deleting even small directories takes a longer time.

In order to try to be a little scientific about it, I started testing a single folder with 38 files that add up to 1.4MB. I have a process that can regenerate this folder after I delete it.

I am deleting from the terminal using: `time rm -rf <folder>`

When I first reboot, deleting this folder takes just over 1 second.

Once I load up my regular suite of apps (browser, calendar, etc.), it starts to take longer.

I can see that after a while it takes 3 seconds to delete the same folder.

Eventually, it seems to cap at nearly 7 seconds.

Throughout my testing, I am somewhere between 10GB and 12GB in use of the available 16GB. At no time is swap space used.

Finally, once I get into this state of deletes taking a longer time, the only remedy seems to be to reboot. Even if I kill every running app (with the exception of the terminal), it still takes a longer time to delete the folder.

A few things I've tried based on other searches is to disable local Time Machine backups and turn off Time Machine altogether. I also ran Disk Utility and did `Verify Disk` and there were no errors. Likewise, I did the `Verify Disk Permissions` and there were no issues.